# How to get youtube user/channel thumbnail?

Tags: youtube

Getting a thumbnail of a YouTube video is done by the following request :

> http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$youtube_v_code.'/1.jpg

How can I get the thumbnail image of a YouTube User or Channel ?

Answer (score 1):

You need use [gdata](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/client-libraries) to access api from google, I think this is the easiest way.